# mockito when().thenReturn() is returning the wrong value

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

Mockito is being used to mock the same method twice, and it should return different values for each mock.
But when I test, it will always consider the latest mocked return value.

The line when(**serviceB.getById**(1)).thenReturn(FirstValue);
is returning the **LatestValue** insted of **FirstValue**

It currently looks like this:

```
when(serviceA.findById(any(String.class))).thenReturn(Object1);
when(serviceB.getById(Object1)).thenReturn(FirstValue);
when(serviceC.convert(any(Integer.class), any(Integer.class))).thenReturn(Object2);
when(serviceB.getById(Object2)).thenReturn(LatestValue);
when(serviceA.save(Object2)).then(returnsFirstArg());
```

How to fix it in a way that **when(serviceB.getById(2)).thenReturn(LatestValue)**; will return **LatestValue** instead of **FirstValue**?

Comment: Did you try using `reset(serviceB)` ?

Comment: Also, can u update the code snippet to show at which line you are trying to fetch the value. Because the param for `getById()` is different, it should never return the same value configured for different param values

Comment: I've just fixed. Please check the answer I'll post in the next minutes.

Comment: Is that because of equals method returning true for your Object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite of being different objects, `Object1` and `Object2` have the same values.

Considering the code snippet that I posted in the question, Mockito was always returning `latestValue` for both lines:

```
when(serviceB.getById(Object1)).thenReturn(FirstValue);
when(serviceB.getById(Object2)).thenReturn(LatestValue);
```

But if I change the `Object1` value before passing to the mock, then it works properly. Something like below solved the problem:

```
Object1.setPropertyValue(anyValueDifferentFromObject2)
```

Comment: I don't see how this question holds any value but glad you fixed it

Comment: There will be value for someone who is a beginner with Mockito and might face the same problem.